# Is there a material table for the Cook Torrance BRDF?

Tags: brdf, physically-based, pbr, material

Is there a material table that lists all the specific values to obtain a certain type of material (e.g: copper or asphalt) available?

I found this table in the paper: [A Reflectance Model for Computer Graphics](http://inst.cs.berkeley.edu/~cs294-13/fa09/lectures/cookpaper.pdf). However, it doesn't really seem to have all the materials I would like to use.

[image]

Currently I am looking for a material table for use in a Path Tracer.